# getElementById() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Tags: python, win32com

I want to do an automation of the Internet Explorer. Open the Internet Explorer, navigate to login.live.com and set a value into the email textbox.

Here's the simple script:

```
import win32com.client
import time

IE = win32com.client.DispatchEx("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = 1
IE.Navigate('login.live.com')

time.sleep(5)

DOC = IE.document
DOC.getElementById('i0116').value = 'test'
```

The last line always returns the following TypeError:

> getElementById() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

When I try to add the value through the console of the Internet Explorer it works.

Btw. the getElementsByTagName() method works without any Errors.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Hope this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9816967/interesting-getelementbyid-takes-exactly-1-argument-2-given-sometimes-it

Comment: got the same error as before. but thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.. I wrote a workaround for this:

```
DOC = IE.Document
inputs = DOC.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('input')

for field in inputs:
    if field.id == 'i0116':
        email = field
        break
email.value = 'example@test.com'
```

For browser automation I recommend to use the [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) library.

Answer (score 0):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024922/1752959) answer suggests you have to use

```
DOC.Body.getElementById('i0116').value = 'test'
```

Comment: I also tried this but then it returns an AttributeError:

AttributeError: <unknown>.getElementById